# statement too large while pushing data into redshift database from python

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I am pushing pandas dataframe in redshift table and getting following error

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO sir_main VALUES " + str(args_str))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: Statement is too large. Statement Size: 58034743 
bytes. Maximum Allowed: 16777216 bytes`
```

And it halts the execution. Is there any way to configure the limit while pushing into database?

Comment: No, also if this is your regular process you should consider changing your approach so that you load your data to s3 first, then use aws copy command.

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading more than a few hundred rows you should save the dataframe as a flat file to S3 and load it into Redshift using `COPY`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html